# How to support both json and urlencoded content-types in Web API

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I want to support all 3 of the following content-types in my controller/action.

```
application/json
application/x-www-form-urlencoded
multipart/form-data
```

with this signature i can support both urlencoded and form data, however a JSON payload does not get bound to `Message`

```cs
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> PostAsync(Message message)
```

If i want to bind a JSON payload to `Message` properly i need to use the `FromBody` attribute like this:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> PostAsync([FromBody]Message message)
```

however doing this starts throwing 415 erros for the other 2 content types I'm interested in.

My question is, how can I provide a single API endpoint to my customers and give them the flexibility of sending data in any of these 3 content types.

Comment: You cannot. You must have separate endpoints. No choice here, that's the way it is.

Comment: Untrue. You can specify input/output formatters to achieve what you're after. See this post about one for application/x-www-form-urlencoded content type https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76067521/net-6-allow-multiple-media-types-for-web-api-parameter

Answer (score 2):

Actually you **can** have a single endpoint accepting multiple content-types:

```cs
[HttpPost]
[Consumes("application/json")]
public async Task<IActionResult> CommonEndpoint([FromBody] JObject payload)
{
    ...
}

[HttpPost]
[Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")]
public async Task<IActionResult> CommonEndpoint(/* this overload doesn't specify the payload in its signature */)
{
    var formFieldsDictionary = HttpContext.Request.Form.Keys
                .ToDictionary(k => k, k => HttpContext.Request.Form[k].FirstOrDefault());

    var payload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(formFieldsDictionary);

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should add the different content types supported using ConsumesAttribute then update your action as follows;

```
[HttpPost]
[Consumes("application/json", "multipart/form-data", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")]
public async Task<IActionResult> PostAsync([FromForm, FromBody, FromQuery]Message message)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should avoid combining the `application/json` and `multipart/form-data` for the same action which will make application unstable.

If you insist on this, you need to implement your own `ModelBinder` by following steps below:

1. `MyComplexTypeModelBinder`

   ```
   public class MyComplexTypeModelBinder : ComplexTypeModelBinder
   {
       public MyComplexTypeModelBinder(IDictionary<ModelMetadata, IModelBinder> propertyBinders, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, bool allowValidatingTopLevelNodes) : base(propertyBinders, loggerFactory, allowValidatingTopLevelNodes)
       {
       }

       protected override Task BindProperty(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
       {
           try
           {
               var result = base.BindProperty(bindingContext);
               if (bindingContext.Result.IsModelSet == false)
               {
                   var request = bindingContext.HttpContext.Request;
                   var body = request.Body;

                   request.EnableRewind();

                   var buffer = new byte[Convert.ToInt32(request.ContentLength)];

                   request.Body.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                   var bodyAsText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);

                   var jobject = JObject.Parse(bodyAsText);
                   var value = jobject.GetValue(bindingContext.FieldName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);                    
                   var typeConverter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(bindingContext.ModelType);
                   var model = typeConverter.ConvertFrom(
                       context: null,
                       culture: CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                       value: value.ToString());
                   bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(model);
                   request.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

               }
               return result;
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {

               throw;
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. `MyComplexTypeModelBinderProvider`

   ```
   public class MyComplexTypeModelBinderProvider : IModelBinderProvider
   {
       public IModelBinder GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context)
       {
           if (context == null)
           {
               throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
           }

           if (context.Metadata.IsComplexType && !context.Metadata.IsCollectionType)
           {
               var propertyBinders = new Dictionary<ModelMetadata, IModelBinder>();
               for (var i = 0; i < context.Metadata.Properties.Count; i++)
               {
                   var property = context.Metadata.Properties[i];
                   propertyBinders.Add(property, context.CreateBinder(property));
               }

               var loggerFactory = context.Services.GetRequiredService<ILoggerFactory>();
               var mvcOptions = context.Services.GetRequiredService<IOptions<MvcOptions>>().Value;
               return new MyComplexTypeModelBinder(
                   propertyBinders,
                   loggerFactory,
                   mvcOptions.AllowValidatingTopLevelNodes);
           }

           return null;
       }

   }
   ```
3. Register `MyComplexTypeModelBinderProvider` in `Startup.cs`

   ```
   services.AddMvc(options => {
       options.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0, new MyComplexTypeModelBinderProvider());
   }).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
   ```