# .NET 6 - Allow multiple media types for web api parameter

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

I am migrating a legacy app from .NET 4.8 to .NET 6. We have a POST API that takes a request body. Apparently some consumer of the API are calling with JSON and others are calling with x-www-form-urlencoded. I want to implement the API in .NET 6 so that it accepts both JSON and x-www-form-urlencoded in order to be backward compatible. Since this functionality was happening implicitly in .NET 4.8, I hope to find a global solution that I don't have to apply at each individual endpoint level.

Here's an example of the API:

```
[ApiController]
public class MyController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("/api/users/{userId}/postfoo"]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Foo(FooRequestModel model, [FromQuery] userId)
    {
        // do work to generate fooResponse.
        return this.Json(fooResponse);
    }
}
```

I have tried adding `[Consumes("application/json", "application/x-www-form-url-encoded")]` at the controller-level, but that still just accepts a json body.

Should the controller not extend ControllerBase? Remove ApiController attribute?

Comment: try adding `[FromForm]` on your model's properties

Comment: `[FromForm]` would allow it accept x-www-form-urlencoded, but not JSON. I want to allow it to be either JSON or x-www-form-urlencoded.

I did try adding both `[FromBody] [FromForm]` but that still just accepted JSON.

Comment: This should just work in Asp.Net Core. You may need to add `[FromBody]` in order for it to apply the appropriate InputFormatter. Also double-check the FormData input formatter is registered on startup (I think it is in the defaults but if not you'll have to add it yourself). `builder.Services.AddControllers(options => inspect options.InputFormatters here)`

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50453578/asp-net-core-fromform-and-frombody-same-action

Comment: hmmm... perhaps adding [FromBody] and explicitly adding the input formatter will work. Hopefully, I don't have to go and list all the formatters (json, form, html, etc) if I add one to that list.

Comment: Yeah it looks like there is no built-in formatter for form data. You could make and register a custom InputFormatter, and don't use the [FromForm] attribute. I'm surprised no one suggested this in the linked question. You won't have to re-specify all the other formatters, just append yours to the end of the list

Comment: Let me know if that works for you, if so I'll write it up as an answer to the linked question

Comment: I was able to get this to work by implementing a custom input formatter. With the formatter, there was no need to add `[FromBody]`, `[FromForm]`, or `[Consumes]`. I also added the `XmlSerializerInputFormatter` and now the functionality fully matches what was happening in .NET 4.8. @AndrewWilliamson feel free to post your answer here & I'll edit to add the example code.

Comment: Here's an alternate approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51677476

Comment: @Michael yes, that would work, but you have to duplicate each endpoint. I'm my case, the application being upgraded had dozens of endpoints, and creating duplicates for each mediatype  was not feasible. Tho I'm sure someone could think up a slick way of auto-duplicating them.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to solve this issue by explicitly specifying some input formatters, including one custom formatter as seen below. With this, I was able to remove any parameter attributes (`[FromBody]`, `[FromForm]`) and did not need `[Consumes]`.

### Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // ...

    services.AddControllers(options =>
    {
        options.InputFormatters.Add(new FormInputFormatter());
        options.InputFormatters.Add(new XmlSerializerInputFormatter(new MvcOptions()));
    });

    // ...
}
```

### FormInputFormatter.cs

```
namespace MyApp;

using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters;

/// <summary>
/// The input formatter for multipart/form-data or x-www-form-urlencoded request bodies.
/// </summary>
public class FormInputFormatter : TextInputFormatter
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="FormInputFormatter"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    public FormInputFormatter()
    {
        this.SupportedEncodings.Add(UTF8EncodingWithoutBOM);
        this.SupportedEncodings.Add(UTF16EncodingLittleEndian);

        this.SupportedMediaTypes.Add("multipart/form-data");
        this.SupportedMediaTypes.Add("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    }

    /// <inheritdoc/>
    public override async Task<InputFormatterResult> ReadRequestBodyAsync(InputFormatterContext context, Encoding encoding)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        }

        if (encoding == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(encoding));
        }

        object _model = null;

        try
        {
            if (context.HttpContext.Request.HasFormContentType)
            {
                Dictionary<string, string> _form = new();
                foreach (string _key in context.HttpContext.Request.Form.Keys)
                {
                    _form.Add(_key, context.HttpContext.Request.Form[_key]);
                }

                string _json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(_form);
                Type _type = context.ModelType;
                _model = JsonSerializer.Deserialize(_json, _type, new JsonSerializerOptions
                {
                    AllowTrailingCommas = true,
                    PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true,
                });
            }
        }
        catch (JsonException _ex)
        {
            var _path = _ex.Path ?? string.Empty;
            var _modelStateException = new InputFormatterException(_ex.Message, _ex);
            context.ModelState.TryAddModelError(_path, _modelStateException, context.Metadata);
            return await InputFormatterResult.FailureAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception _ex)
        {
            context.ModelState.TryAddModelError(string.Empty, _ex, context.Metadata);
            return await InputFormatterResult.FailureAsync();
        }

        if (_model == null && !context.TreatEmptyInputAsDefaultValue)
        {
            return await InputFormatterResult.FailureAsync();
        }

        return await InputFormatterResult.SuccessAsync(_model);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 You, my friend, deserve a Bells! Having this functionality out-of-the-box in .net framework was awesome. Just another disappointment in .net 6 that we have to "make a plan" but thank you very much for sharing this.

Comment: @Jimbo Right?! We noticed a lot of annoying differences between .NET Framework and .NET 6. Switching to use System.Text.Json especially proved to be a big pain in the butt.