# Convert IFormCollection to model

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

I created a custom InputFormatter (see [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76067521/net-6-allow-multiple-media-types-for-web-api-parameter) for details on why and how this was implemented). With this InputFormatter, I am handling form data which I can retrieve via `HttpContext.Request.Form`. I handles simple mapping just fine, but it does not handle arrays. When using the normal `FromForm` attribute, form data with arrays can be sent in multiple formats. For example:

if my action method takes a list of `Foo`s, and that model looks like this:

```
public class Foo
{
    public Bar[] Bar { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public string Blah { get; set; }
}
```

then all of these Key names are valid:

- `[foo][0][bar][0][blah]`
- `[0][bar][0][blah]`
- `foo[0].bar[0].blah`
- `[0].bar[0].blah`

I'm trying to figure out a way to get my input formatter to handle all the same scenarios. Ideally, I want to re-use whatever code Microsoft uses to convert IFormCollection to the desired model when we use `[FromForm]`. (It'd be really nice if they gave us a form input handler like they give us JSON handlers and XML handlers!)

Comment: Could you please share how you are sending request? You can parse your IFormCollection into dictionary then into a class. It would great if  you could share your request and controller details.

Comment: Form input handling is built into MVC. Why are you building a custom formatter?

Comment: Because .NET 6 does not allow you to accept both JSON and form inputs on the same action method. .NET 4.8 does, and we want to be backward compatible & know that our client apps use both media types. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76067521/net-6-allow-multiple-media-types-for-web-api-parameter